# Updating Big Commerce to the new analytics.js

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, bigcommerce

I'm working on a site and I updated the tracking code to the new analytics.js I transferred their site and everything is working except for conversion.
It's a Big Commerce site so I can't touch server side script but 
this what they generate

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
 if(typeof(pageTracker) != 'undefined') {
 pageTracker._addTrans(
'358',
'Backyard Toy Company ',
'0.01',
'0.00',
'0.00',
'Lakewood',
'New Jersey',
'United States'
);
 pageTracker._addItem(
'358',
'1336',
'test',
'',
'0.01',
'1'
);
  pageTracker._trackTrans();
}
});
</script>
```

I updated the client side code to this

```
   ga('require', 'ecommerce', 'ecommerce.js');   // Load the ecommerce plug-in.

  // START CUSTOM CODE
  function old2new() {
     // define object that can route old methods to new methods
     this._addTrans = addTrans;
     this._addItem = addItem;
     this._trackTrans = trackTrans;
  }

  function addTrans(orderID,store,total,tax,shipping,city,state,country) {
    // remap _addTrans
   ga('ecommerce:addTransaction', {
      'id': orderID,
      'affiliation': store,
      'revenue': total,
      'tax': tax,
      'shipping': shipping,
   });
  }

  function addItem(orderID,sku,product,variation,price,qty) {
    // remap _addItem
  ga('ecommerce:addItem', {
    'id': orderID,
    'sku': sku,
    'name': product,
    'category': variation,
    'price': price,
    'quantity': qty
  });
 }

function trackTrans() {
  ga('send', 'ecommerce'); 
}

// instantiate converter using name of old Google tracking object
// bigcommerce code will use this and be none the wiser
var pageTracker = new old2new();
// END CUSTOM CODE
```

I'm sorry I'm a newbie, but I looked all over can't figure out why it's not working.

Comment: I don't understand the old2new function (which never seems to be called) and I do not understand why you wrap addTransaction into another function - the code seems to be either incomplete or wrong ( do not see any remapping take place even though it's announced in a comment and I do not understand why you thing mapping functions would be necessary).

Comment: function old2new is being assigned to the variable pageTracker so that when BigCommerce sends their data to _addTrans it should reach function addTrans I'm not sure why remapping was necessary but I was working off code that BigCommerce was using for ga.js (the previous version of google-analytics) Thank You @Eike

Comment: Can you also tell me where you got the documentation which asked you to send ecommerce data using ga('send', 'ecommerce'); ?

Comment: Thank You very much! I would promise I copied it from google anaylitics but checked again and your right it's suppose to be ga('send', 'ecommerce'); not sure how I made such a dumb mistake thanks everyone @Avi

Comment: Actually, it was a bug in the documentation that we fixed. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: when I wrote it's suppose to be ga('send', 'ecommerce'); I meant ga('ecommerce:send'); as you probably figured out Thank again to all of you making this an excellent forum

Answer (score 0):

I think the send method is supposed to be something like:

```
ga('ecommerce:send');
```

If this does not work, you can do the following and see if find something else that is wrong:

Can you put an alert in all three functions and make sure that it is being called correctly?

Also, there might be a bug in the code that might be affected by the overridden `this`. Can you rewrite the methods like the following and see if that works:

```
  function addTrans(orderID,store,total,tax,shipping,city,state,country) {
   // alert("in addTrans");
   ga.call(window, 'ecommerce:addTransaction', {
      'id': orderID,
      'affiliation': store,
      'revenue': total,
      'tax': tax,
      'shipping': shipping,
   });
  }

  function addItem(orderID,sku,product,variation,price,qty) {
  // alert("in addTrans");
  ga.call(window, 'ecommerce:addItem', {
    'id': orderID,
    'sku': sku,
    'name': product,
    'category': variation,
    'price': price,
    'quantity': qty
  });
 }

function trackTrans() {
  // alert("in Trans");
  ga.call(window, 'ecommerce:send'); 
}
```